# Cannot explain invalid CSRF token rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, fetch, backend, csrf

I am currently stuck on a bug in my project which is a rails api backend with a react/redux frontend.

For auth im using an httponly cookie and csrf tokens provided by rails, and placed in the headers of my requests through my api wrapper.

My application has numerous non-get requests and i have no CSRF problems with any of them but i'm experiencing a strange behavior from the logout action.

My logout request is a delete request and if i log in, then immediately log out the request fails due to an invalid csrf token, I have made sure i'm issuing one after login.

in my attempts to debug this i have pored over the requests in devtools and had the server logging each csrf token to the console as it's created and i have my client logging the token with each request. I can confirm that the last issued csrf token matches the one used for the logout request and it still comes back as invalid.

To make things stranger yet: If i refresh the page the logout request succeeds though no new requests to the backend have been made and with the same csrf token that failed in the previous request.

I'm feeling pretty overwhelmed and I have no idea what to do i feel like I've tried everything

Comment: Could you be seeing this? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11476

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in my api wrapper, the wrapper wasn't setting the x-csrf header value correctly and though my browser had the correct cookie, the header was being set to undefined